# Error SocketTimeoutException connecting to google in android

Tags: java, android, httpurlconnection, socket-timeout-exception

i'm having a problem with the connection for my app (Android). I'm using the following code to check if i have internet connection.

```
    ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager)context
            .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

    NetworkInfo activeNetwork = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    if (activeNetwork != null && activeNetwork.isConnected()) {
        try {
            URL url = new URL("http://www.google.com/");
            HttpURLConnection urlc = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
            urlc.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "test");
            urlc.setRequestProperty("Connection", "close");
            urlc.setConnectTimeout(5000); // mTimeout is in seconds
            urlc.connect();
            if (urlc.getResponseCode() == 200) {
                return true;
            } else {
            return false;
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.i("warning", "Error checking internet connection", e);
            return false;
        }
    }
```

After trying several times, i encounter that the problem is that im doing ping to "www.google.com.". 
I dont understand why is this happening. This code was woking fine for the last 2 years in my project.

Comment: Try these things: 1- removing http://, 2- put https://, 3: Set port explicitly (80). I mean not the three at the same time, just test the first and if it didn't work try the second, and so on

Comment: Thanks for the answer, i was reading documentation an i found the root of the problem. Google has shutdown the autentication for some services and i'm struggling to fix this. My greatest issue is that i can modify the code to the devices and i can update because of this connectivity problem.
There will be some way to "Trick" the device to response and dont failed this test without changing the code?

Answer (score 0):

If you are testing this on a latest version of android, then you need to verify that you have whitelisted domains. You should read below:
https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-config

As a quick fix you can add below property to application tag:

```html
android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
```